# Some images do not load in chrome, content security policy

Tags: google-chrome, security

So my chrome has been throwing errors on common websites:

Refused to load the image 'http://images.craigslist.org/00u0u_xlyBmVuxhm_600x450.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src chrome-search: data: https: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

Here's an example URL with the problem: https://sacramento.craigslist.org/cto/4962253523.html

I'm running the latest version of chrome with uMatrix and uBlock, but setting those to allow all does not resolve the issue. Loading the page without HTTPS makes everything load fine. I understand that loading insecure images on an HTTPS page can allow MITM attacks, but I really don't care if everyone knows 
I'm looking for a car. Is there a way to whitelist sites against the content security policy?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running the latest version of chrome with uMatrix

This must be because you have "Strict HTTPS" enabled in uMatrix. Just disable it -- for the site or globally, your choice.